# Where macros variable created? and size of the variable?

Tags: c, macros

I have doubts about macros, When we create like the following

```
      #define DATA 40
```

where DATA can be create? and i need to know size also?and type of DATA?

In java we create macro along with data type,

and what about macro function they are all inline function?

Comment: Macro simply replace the symbol.

Comment: It's of type 'sourceText'

Answer (score 3):

Macros are essentially text substitutions.

`DATA` does not exist beyond the pre-processing stage. The compiler never sees it. Since no variable is created, we can't talk about its data type, size or address.

Comment: To be precise, macro replacement substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are literally pasted into the code. They are not "parsed", but expanded. The compiler does not see `DATA`, but `40`. This is why you must be careful because macros are not like normal functions or variables. See [gcc's documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html).

> A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever
>   the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro. There
>   are two kinds of macros. They differ mostly in what they look like
>   when they are used. Object-like macros resemble data objects when
>   used, function-like macros resemble function calls.
>
> You may define any valid identifier as a macro, even if it is a C
>   keyword. The preprocessor does not know anything about keywords. This
>   can be useful if you wish to hide a keyword such as const from an
>   older compiler that does not understand it. However, the preprocessor
>   operator defined (see Defined) can never be defined as a macro, and
>   C++'s named operators (see C++ Named Operators) cannot be macros when
>   you are compiling C++.

Answer (score 0):

macro's are not present in your final executable. They present in your source code only.macro's are processed during `pre-processing` stage of compilation.You can find more info about macro's [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/c-macros-inline-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor directives like #define are replaced with the corresponding text during the preprocessing phase of compilation, and are (almost) never represented in the final executable.

Comment: To be precise, macro replacement substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text.

Comment: "*almost*"? Macros are fully gone after the pre-processing.

Comment: When macro replacement occurs, the source text has already been parsed into preprocessor tokens (such as strings and identifiers) and is not parsed again after macro replacement. This means you cannot, for example, use `#define Q "` and `Q abc Q` to form the string `" abc "`. Macro replacement substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text.